# Task hangs if terminal window doesn't lose focus

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

While debugging the problem, I minimized the code to the one below to understand why I have the problem. The program is a console application.

The code simply creates an instance of a third-party class and subscribes to an event that does nothing. When I run the code as is:

1. Line (9) is never executed unless the terminal window loses focus or I press the Enter key multiple times. It's like it's stuck on the line (8). If I replace the line (8) with any other method from ThridParty, such as `obj.MethodX()` I get the same problem.
2. If I delete line (8), then I won't have this problem.
3. If I remove Task.Run (line 5) and let the code on lines (7-9) run outside of Task.Run, then I won't have this problem.
4. If I uncomment lines 24-25 and 32-33 then I won't have this problem.

I looked at the `ThirdParty` constructor through dotPeek. It has a few lazy initializations (`Lazy<>`) of some pluggins and services. So it's likely that calling any `obj.MethodX()` initializes those plugins and services first. But I still don't understand why it matters if lines 7-9 and 22-34 run on separate threads. It seems as if one of them is starving.

```
1.  class MyService
2.  {
3.      public void Start()
4.      {
5.          Task.Run(() =>
6.          {
7.              var obj = new ThirdParty();
8.              obj.ItemChanged += (...) => {};
9.              Console.WriteLine("Instantiated ThirdParty");
10.          });
11.      } 
12.  }

13. internal class Program
14. {
15.    static async Task Main(string[] args)
16.    {
17.        var service = new MyService();
18.        service.Start();
19.
20.        await Task.Run(() =>
21.        {
22.            while (true)
23.            {
24.                // if (Console.KeyAvailable)
25.                // {
26.                       var read = Console.ReadKey(true);
27.                       if (read.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
28.                       {
29.                           service.Stop();
30.                           return;
31.                        }
32.                // }
33.                // Thread.Sleep(100);    
34.            }
35.       });
36.   }
37. }
```

Comment: The terminal will stop reading from your programs stdout when the user (you) selects text. Which leads to other `Console` methods blocking until the terminal continues to read data.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, what do you mean? I don't select any text.

Comment: So in other words, "Why is unnamed third party software crashing in a strange way?" Pretty hard to guess. I wonder if you have to press enter to clear an error dialog that you can't see..? Was this third party class designed to work in a console app?

Comment: @JohnWu, it doesn't crash. I never said it crashed anything.

Comment: Does the third party require a STA thread?